# Instagram API working local but not on server

Tags: curl, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to call the instagram api with a server.

I tried following on my local system:

```
curl https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list   -->works perfectly
curl https://www.instagram.com/zitate.flx/?__a=1   -->works perfectly
```

on the linux server:

```
curl https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list   -->works perfectly
curl https://www.instagram.com/zitate.flx/?__a=1   -->doesn't work
```

My question: why does the request to the instagram API work on my local system but not on the server?

Comment: it is probably because of your sever's country. In many countries Instagram doesn't give you information about the page if you are not logged in.

Comment: @ikibir 
thanks for the fast respond. Is there a way how I can access the api with the server?

Comment: first login your account with your credentials or sesion_key then you can use this session to get information

Comment: @unkownprogrammer I am adding an example code for login

Comment: @ikibir can you please make an example of a country in which instagram gives info without logging in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

def create_session():       
     cookie = {"name": "sessionid", "value":"{this is your session id}"}
     session = requests.Session()
     session.cookies.set(**cookie)
     return session

s = create_session()
response = s.get(https://www.instagram.com/zitate.flx/?__a=1)
```